# Two tables under each other, align the columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two tables under each other. One table is representing the headers, the other one the table data.

Please see the pic ->  So just like in a normal table. Data-Columns should align on Head-Columns

[image]

so that the **data** for **Text1** fits in the **header** **Text1** for example

Also please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yffmgzu5/43/)

I have tried to set a specific width to `td` and `th` but it seems not to work.

Could anyone please help how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
</table>

<table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-striped responsive-table' id='TableBody'>
```

from user code.. every thing will be good

Comment: Why? The seperation into two tables is a must.

Comment: this separation is the main reason for distortion for table design

Comment: The background behind this is: I want to fix the header-content when vertical scrolling. On horizontal scroll, the headshould scroll normally.

Thats why I want two tables, so I can scroll the head-table horizontal when the user scrolls the content table horizontal (with JS). On vertical scroll the head is naturally fixed (because two seperate tables).

If you could provide me this behavior when everything is in one table, then this would be appreciated. Otherwise I need two tables, with aligned columns

Comment: Solved the scrolling issue with one table with this code:

document.getElementById("TableHead").addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
   this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});

Comment: So how is this looking now.. can you please show .. another fiddle

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yffmgzu5/84/ (i fixed the strange looking border by setting border-width and a opacity value for the border)